# JavaScript IF statement not recognizing value

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

```js
function init(){
 document.getElementById("add_soldier_button").onclick = addSoldier;
 document.getElementById("deploy_squad_button").onclick = deploySquad;
}
function Soldier(allegiance, armored, weapons){
 this.allegiance = allegiance;
 this.weapons = weapons;
 this.armored = armored;
 
}
function checkSoldierConstraints(allegiance, armored, weapons){
 
 if(weapons.length == 0)
  return "No weapons specified";
 
 if(armored == "")
  return "Armored not set";
 
 if(allegiance == "")
  return "No allegiance specified";
 
 if (allegiance.value != "khorne" || "slaanesh" || "nurgle" || "tzeentch")
  return "allegiance must be to khorne, slaanesh, nurgle, or tzeentch";
 
 if (weapons.value  != "chainsword" || "plasma cannon" || "bolt rifle" || "magic")
  return "Weapon must be a chainsword, plasma cannon, bolt rifle , or magic";
  
 if ( allegiance.value == "tzeentch" && weapons.value != "magic") 
                return " tzeentch can only use magic";  
 
 soldiers.push(new Soldier(allegiance, armored, weapons));
 return "Creating Soldier";
 
 
 
 
 }
 
 var soldiers = new Array();
function addSoldier(){
 
 
 var allegiance_text = document.getElementById("allegiance_input");
 var armored_text = document.getElementById("armored_input");
 var weapon1_text = document.getElementById("weapon1_input");
 var weapon2_text = document.getElementById("weapon2_input");
 
 var weapons = new Array();
 if(weapon1_text.value != "")
  weapons.push(weapon1_text.value);
 if(weapon2_text.value != "")
  weapons.push(weapon2_text.value);
 
 alert(checkSoldierConstraints(allegiance_text.value, armored_text.value, weapons));
}

function deploySquad(){
 var squad_table = document.getElementById("squad_table");
 while(soldiers.length){
 soldier = soldiers.pop();
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  var td3 = document.createElement("td");
 
  td1.innerHTML = soldier.allegiance;
  td2.innerHTML = soldier.armored;
  
 
  if(soldier.weapons.length > 1)
   td3.innerHTML = soldier.weapons[0] + ", " + soldier.weapons[1];
  else
   td3.innerHTML = soldier.weapons[0];
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  row.appendChild(td3);
  squad_table.appendChild(row);
 } 
} 
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>

<title> Brandon Bell </title>

<script src = "objects_part2.js"> </script>

<style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      text-align: center;
    } 
</style>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Squad Builder</h1>
    <input type="text" id="allegiance_input" placeholder=" Allegiance">
    <input type="text" id="armored_input" placeholder="Armored (True/False)"><br>
    <input type="text" id="weapon1_input" placeholder="Weapon 1">
    <input type="text" id="weapon2_input" placeholder="Weapon 2"><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="add_soldier_button" value="Add Soldier">
    <input type="button" id="deploy_squad_button" value="Deploy Squad">
</br></br>
<table id="squad_table" width=50%>
  <tr>
    <th>Allegiance</th>
    <th>Armored</th>
    <th>Weapons</th>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to get some if statements to work. particularly the one that if you are tzeenech that you have to use only magic. but even when i put in the allegiance of tzeenech it says that i have to pick the ones that explained in my code. but when i use the ones i said i could use it wont let me. I also dont understand if its because i did .value or not.

Comment: You have type `tzeenech ` wrong in your `if()` condition `|| "tzeentch")`That isn't going to fix your problem but thought I would point it out.

Comment: how so? what is it that i did wrong

Comment: Unrelated, but you really should consider marking some of your [**other questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7759732/brandon-bell#top-posts) as resolved.

Comment: Also to add: Your `checkSoldierConstraints()` argument contain the values of the inputs so you don't need to use `allegiance.value !=` in your condition as it will return `undefined` I would suggest you use `console.log();` and debug your source code to ensure the correct/expected values are being passed in the function calls.